# Creating Artificial Signals

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, time-frequency

I've tried posting this on the Signal Processing StackExchange, but with little avail, as it is rather sparsely populated. Since I am using MATLAB, I hope someone here can help just as well.

I'm trying to design a sample signal that has two "components". I want the signal to look like the upper left figure, with the two components shown on the right. The time frequency spectrum is shown in the bottom left.

[image: Signal and Frequency Spectrum]

Admittedly, my knowledge of signals is not up to par, but even after several hours of trying to fiddle around with combinations of chirps, sincs and sine functions I was unable to reproduce exactly what I have in mind. The following code comes to something that has a slight resemblance to what I try to achieve:

```
fs = 5000;
x0 = 1;
t = -x0:1/fs:x0;
yi = cos(t).*sinc(t).*chirp(t,150,0.2,250,'quadratic'); 
yj = cos(t).*sinc(t).*chirp(t,50,0.4,150,'quadratic'); 
subplot(2,2,1)
plot(t,yi+yj)
subplot(2,2,2)
plot(t,yj)
subplot(2,2,3)
spectrogram(yi+yj,512,511,256,fs,'yaxis')
subplot(2,2,4)
plot(t,yi)
```

This gives the following signal:

[image: my attempt]

This is good, but still not satisfactory. So today I tried a more thorough approach to understanding how chirps and sinc/gauspuls functions operate, and I am getting a bit of a hang for it, without understanding the backgrounds too much.

From my understanding a gauspuls has a constant frequency with diminishing amplitude. A chirp has a continuous frequency that can be speficied as the frequency at t0 and t1, and is interpolated in between. Now what I don't understand is why this doesn't seem to show well in the spectrogram.

Say I create a chirp of the following form:

```
fs = 1000;
scope = 10;
t = -scope:1/fs:scope;
yj = chirp(t,0.5,10,2,'quadratic');
plot(t,yj)
```

I figured that the spectrogram would show a ridge that populates the frequency spectrum between 0.5Hz to 2Hz, but the spectrogram gives me a y-axis resolution up to above 500Hz:

[image: sample chirp]

Can someone explain to me how I can get a clearer spectrogram for a signal such as this?

Additionally, how do I visualize this "tapering off" effect of the upper ridhe in the spectrogram that I posted at the top?

Comment: I believe that your second image and the first one are practically the same, you just have different plotting and sample points